# Restoring of django database taking more time

Tags: python, django, database-backups

For Django database backups and restore. I used this tool https://github.com/django-dbbackup/django-dbbackup. It is taking so much time to restore the database.

It is taking 3hours of time to restore a `500MB` Compressed file. I used the below command.

```
time python manage.py dbrestore -i django_db_production_backup_20171109_0200.dump.gz -z
```

Is there any alternative methods to reduce the time consumption.

Answer (score 1):

Use the native tools of your database. E.g., PostgreSQL has `pg_dump` and `pg_restore`, which probably would backup and restore a 500 MB database in less than a minute.